# packagist complains on new package InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, package, composer-php

my first package for composer in packagist. I actually wrote it for my own project, but I cannot use it anywhere!

when I do

```
composer require wearede/tbcpay-php
```

it complains

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                       
  Could not find package wearede/tbcpay-php at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). C  
  heck the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

since this is my first composer package, i'm at loss.

Comment: are you running php: >=5.5.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/wearede/tbcpay-php), your package doesn't have any stable releases (versions). It only has a `master` branch (branches are prefixed with `dev-` in Composer/Packagist).

So there are 2 solutions:

- Create a release of your package, by creating a git tag. E.g: `git tag v1.0.0; git push origin --tags`
- Allow to install unstable packages by adding `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to the application's `composer.json` file (as mentioned by @NickOS)

Comment: But I have "minimum_stability": "dev" this.

https://github.com/wearede/tbcpay-php/blob/master/composer.json

or is it with underscore?

Comment: @salivan that setting applies to packages installed when running `composer update` in the `wearede/tbcpay-php` repository. In this case, you're in another application, requiring `wearede/tbcpay-php`. This other application has a `composer.json` file as well and it should get this `minimum-stability: dev` setting (underscore was a typo).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a setting in the composer.json file in the tbcpay-php bundle

```
"minimum-stability" : "dev"
```

Which defines your dev branch as stable, and looks for a stable branch to install the package.

You can read more about the stability flags here:

https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html